# How to combine transaction and security rules on Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

**Hello !**

First of all I have a quick question. When the transaction fails, it is restarted with the basic state of the database. I want to know, do we enter each time it fails in the completion block or do we enter it only when the maximum number of attempts is reached.

Now the real problem :

In my iOS application I have to increment the number of messages sent by the user in the "Users" table of the database when this user sends a message in the "Message" table. So I decide to use a transaction to make sure the database stays consistent.
Here is the code:

```
private static func createNewTradeDb(_ content : String){
        
        let now = DateFormatter()
        now.dateStyle = .medium
        now.timeStyle = .medium
        now.locale = Locale(identifier: "FR-fr")
        dbRef.runTransactionBlock ({ (currentData) -> TransactionResult in
            let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            if var dbInfo = currentData.value as? [String : Any] {
                var message = dbInfo["Message"] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                var userInfo = dbInfo["Users"] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                var currentMessageInfo = messageInfo[userId!] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                var currentUserInfo = userInfo[userId!] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                
                currentMessageInfo["date"] = now.string(from: Date())
                currentMessageInfo["content"] = content
                
                currentUserInfo["messageCounter"] = self.messageCounter + 1

                messageInfo[userId!] = currentMessageInfo
                userInfo[userId!] = currentUserInfo
                dbInfo["Message"] = MessageInfo
                dbInfo["Users"] = userInfo
                currentData.value = dbInfo
                
                //We send a notification if the writing finished
                let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "writingMessageFinished")
                let notification = Notification(name: name)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
            }
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }){
            (error,commited,snapshot) in
            if error != nil{
                //We send a notification if the writing failed
                let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "writingMessageFailed")
                let notification = Notification(name: name)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I send a message from an account I get a "Permission Denied". My security rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$userId": {
        ".read": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid", 
      },
    },
    "Message": {
      "$userId": {
        ".read": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid", 
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Indeed as I did not specify anything for the database in general "Rules" : I imagine that these lines are missing:

```
if var dbInfo = currentData.value as? [String : Any] {
                var tradeInfo = dbInfo["Trade"] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                var userInfo = dbInfo["Users"] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
```

Only if I change the rules to allow reading or writing to these locations, then the subpaths ($userId) cannot be more restrictive as stated in the doc. And so I could no longer enforce that a user only writes or reads to their id field.

I would like to know how I can arrange to make a transaction on two different tables "Users" and "Message".

Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

> When the transaction fails, it is restarted with the basic state of the database. I want to know, do we enter each time it fails in the completion block or do we enter it only when the maximum number of attempts is reached.

The completion block of your transaction handler is only called once the transaction completes, so it will be called only once. Only the first block is called multiple times, in the case of retries.